# What is a blade directive in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, templates, laravel-blade, directive

In a blade template, you see @section, @content, @yield etc. What are blade directives? Are they comparable to PHP or HTML? There doesn't seem to be much explanation on Laravel syntax in the framework.

Answer (score 0):

At a basic level Blade is a **templating language** that compiles down to PHP and HTML.

When you use `@section`, `@content` or `@yield` in a `.blade` template file it will be compiled down to PHP.

If you want to dive in exactly to how it works try looking through the [tests](https://github.com/laravel/framework/tree/5.4/tests/View) in frameworks Github or taking a look at the [API](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/View.html).